# How to use Belongs table in select

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

In laravel5 i belongsTo a model in a model that is

```
 public function LeaveCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\LeaveCategories','leave_category_id','id');
}
```

Then i query in a controller that is

```
$userInfo = Leave::select(DB::raw('count(leaves.leave_category_id) as category_used'),
        'LeaveCategories.id','LeaveCategories.category','LeaveCategories.category_num')
        ->where('Leaves.leave_date','>=', $first_day_this_year)
        ->where('Leaves.leave_date','<=', $last_day_this_year)
        ->where('Leaves.leave_status', 1)
        ->groupBy('Leaves.leave_category_id','LeaveCategories.category','LeaveCategories.category_num','LeaveCategories.id')
        ->get();
```

But it shows a error that is Unknown column 'LeaveCategories.id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

You use `QueryBuilder`, but `belongsTo` is ActiveRecord. Use that:

```
$userInfo = Leave::with('LeaveCategories')->where('Leaves.leave_date','>=', $first_day_this_year)
        ->where('Leaves.leave_date','<=', $last_day_this_year)
        ->where('Leaves.leave_status', 1)
        ->groupBy('Leaves.leave_category_id','LeaveCategories.category','LeaveCategories.category_num','LeaveCategories.id')
        ->get([DB::raw('count(leaves.leave_category_id) as category_used'),
        'LeaveCategories.id','LeaveCategories.category','LeaveCategories.category_num']);
```

Comment: i already did it using querybuilder, i need to know that is it possible in eloquent orm.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And my answer use `eloquent`, not use `querybuilder `.

Comment: i will try it.i have one more ques. i already join LeaveCategories in model.if i amn't call with('LeaveCategories').is it works?

Comment: If i use closure,it's work.Otherwise shows error.Not found column